# What is a common verb to express to put more pressure on the fold when folding a piece of paper?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I want to bend a piece of paper to fold it and I want 2 parts of the folded paper are as flat as possible.

In order to do that I will put more pressure on the fold of the folded paper to make the 2 parts as flat as possible.

**What is a common verb to express to put more pressure on the fold when folding a piece of paper?**

Can I say "**I creased the fold to make the paper stay flat**"?

Comment: Yes, but maybe simple to say "Make a crease so the paper stays flat ..." or "Form a sharp crease so ...". For my understanding a fold is looser (cannot think of better word here) than a crease. See also https://wikidiff.com/crease/fold .

Comment: *Flatten* the crease.

Comment: _Flatten_ the crease by _pressing_ along it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, does "smooth the crease" mean "flatten the crease"?

Comment: **Crease** is to make the initial fold. which might just be a wrinkle. As mentioned, *flattened* might be used, or *pressed*, or a synonym for *press* (as verb).